# Return list of not matched ids in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to return the list of ids that don't have match in the index.

i.e I have this query:

```
{
    "ids" : {
        "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
    }
}
```

Say, I have only record with _id 1 in index, thus the result gives me `1`. What I want instead is to have `["4", "100"]` (those that not presented in index) as the result. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: If you only have _id 1 in your index, how could you possibly have a query returns a list with 4 and 100? Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I have to use multi-get API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_retrieving_multiple_documents.html
which returns `"found": false` for the documents that weren't found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `must_not` in a query to obtain documents that do not meet a criteria

Comment: updated my answer to make it more clear, what I need